# Create new array by joining on two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have two different arrays, one filled with unique currencies and one filled with unique countries.

Both of the arrays have a column which matches, in the currency array it is called `counter_currency` and in the country array it is just called `reporter`.

The reason I am wanting to create this new array, is because the original currencies array is no longer sufficient for me. I now want a two digit ISO code which is found in the countries array to be included with my currencies data.

The currency array is an array of objects that has this format:

```
export interface CurrencyInterface {
    currency_code: string;
    base_currency_code: string;
    base_currency: string;
    counter_currency_code: string;
    counter_currency: string;
}
```

and the currency array is an array of objects with this format:

```
export interface ReporterInterface {
    reporter_code: number;
    reporter: string;
    reporter_iso: string;
    reporter_iso_2?: string;
}
```

I fill both arrays using a service but I now need some way to create an array that has all the existing currency data but in addition, where `reporter = counter_currency`, I also want the `reporter_iso_2` code.

I've tried playing with concat and push but had no luck.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

I have now tried this:

```
testArray: Array<any>;

addCounterIso() {
     this.testArray = this.filteredCurrencies.map(c => 
            (
                {
                    ...c,
                    reporter_iso_2: this.filteredCountries.find(x = > x.reporter == c.counter_currency).reporter_iso_2
                }
            ));
}
```

but receive the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(predicate: (this: void, value: ReporterInterface, index: number, obj: ReporterInterface[]) => value is ReporterInterface, thisArg?: any): ReporterInterface', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: void, value: ReporterInterface, index: number, obj: ReporterInterface[]) => value is ReporterInterface'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(predicate: (value: ReporterInterface, index: number, obj: ReporterInterface[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): ReporterInterface', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: ReporterInterface, index: number, obj: ReporterInterface[]) => unknown'.
```

Comment: can you show some demo

Comment: could you show source data as text and desired data as text?

Comment: Show `this.filteredCurrencies` and `this.filteredCountries`. console and show the output

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz, I think something else is causing the error. Not map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxmy9j?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
result = [];

addCounterIso() {
     var self = this
        this.result = this.currencyArray.map(function(item) {
          var reporter = self.reporterArray.find(x => x.reporter == item.counter_currency);
          return {
            ...item,
            reporter_iso_2: reporter ? reporter.reporter_iso_2 : null
          };
        });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is resulting in a 'No overload matches this call' error for me so I will play around some more

Answer (score 1):

Using `Map` collection, `map` method and `spread` operator:

```js
let currencyArray = [
  {
    currency_code: "A",
    base_currency_code: "B",
    base_currency: "C",
    counter_currency_code: "D",
    counter_currency: "Euro"
  }
];

let reporterArray = [
  {
    reporter_code: "E",
    reporter: "Euro",
    reporter_iso: "F",
    reporter_iso_2: "G"
  },
   {
    reporter_code: "J",
    reporter: "Rupee",
    reporter_iso: "L",
    reporter_iso_2: "M"
  }
];

const currencyMap = new Map(currencyArray.map(o => [o.counter_currency, o]));    
const result = reporterArray.map(a => ({ ...a, ...currencyMap.get(a.reporter) }));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Adrita Sharma's answer of course works, but its O(n<sup>2</sup>) (Assuming Javascript's `Array.prototype.find()` takes O(n)).

If you are sure however that your `counter_currency`/`reporter` is unique, then you could first sort the two arrays on `counter_currency`/`reporter`, which would be approx. O(logn) for both. Then merge them by traversing only the `currency` array once. Which finally would be around O(n logn).

**note:** Works only if `counter_currency`/`reporter` is unique and sortable.